Quarkus - Mixing Quarkus REST and RESTEasy Issue
I'm new to the framework, working step by step with Udemy course from 2021 by Antonio Goncalves.
I'm trying to create a microservice proxy, which will be injected by @RestClient.
I have created the interface as follows:
package org.agoncal.quarkus.microservices.book

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.Operation
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient


@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "number.proxy")
@Path("/api/numbers")
interface NumberProxy {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Operation(
        summary = "Generate books numbers",
        description = "ISBN13/ISBN10 numbers",
    )
    fun generateIsbnNumbers(): IsbnThirteen;
}


This is the resource which uses the proxy:
package org.agoncal.quarkus.microservices.book

import jakarta.inject.Inject
import jakarta.ws.rs.*
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.Operation
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.tags.Tag
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RestClient

import org.jboss.logging.Logger
import java.time.Instant

@Path("/api/books")
@Tag(name = "Book REST endpoint")
class BookResource {

    @Inject
    lateinit var logger: Logger

    @RestClient
    lateinit var numberProxy: NumberProxy

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Operation(summary = "Creates a book", description = "Creates a book with ISBN number")
    fun createABook(
        @FormParam("title") title: String,
        @FormParam("author") author: String,
        @FormParam("genre") genre: String,
        @FormParam("year") yearOfPublication: Int
    ): Response {
       //...
    }
}

I had to add the relevant dependecy by using the mvn command as shown in the course:
mvn quarkus:add-extension -Dextension="rest-client"
but when I try to debug I get the following trace and the service does not launch.
[INFO] Invoking kotlin:2.0.0:test-compile (test-compile) @ rest-book
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 61163
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:61163', transport: 'socket'
Press [e] to edit command line args (currently ''), [h] for more options>
2024-08-01 16:56:44,248 INFO  [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Attempting to start live reload endpoint to recover from previous Quarkus startup failure
2024-08-01 16:56:44,756 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.common.deployment.ResteasyReactiveCommonProcessor#checkMixingStacks threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Mixing Quarkus REST and RESTEasy Classic server parts is not supported
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.common.deployment.ResteasyReactiveCommonProcessor.checkMixingStacks(ResteasyReactiveCommonProcessor.java:108)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.doRunWith(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2516)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2495)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:483)

    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:335)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:254)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:58)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:91)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:430)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:57)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:138)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:93)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:131)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:62)
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.common.deployment.ResteasyReactiveCommonProcessor#checkMixingStacks threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Mixing Quarkus REST and RESTEasy Classic server parts is not supported
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.common.deployment.ResteasyReactiveCommonProcessor.checkMixingStacks(ResteasyReactiveCommonProcessor.java:108)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.doRunWith(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2516)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2495)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:483)

    at io.quarkus.builder.Execution.run(Execution.java:123)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildExecutionBuilder.execute(BuildExecutionBuilder.java:79)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:159)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:331)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Mixing Quarkus REST and RESTEasy Classic server parts is not supported
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.common.deployment.ResteasyReactiveCommonProcessor.checkMixingStacks(ResteasyReactiveCommonProcessor.java:108)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.doRunWith(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2516)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2495)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:483)

also here is my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.agoncal.quarkus.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-book</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.13.0</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>3.13.0</quarkus.platform.version>
        <skipITs>true</skipITs>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.2.5</surefire-plugin.version>
        <kotlin.version>2.0.0</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                            <goal>native-image-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parameters>true</parameters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <source>src/main/java</source>
                                <source>target/generated-sources/annotations</source>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <source>src/test/java</source>
                                <source>target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations</source>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>testCompile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <skipITs>false</skipITs>
                <quarkus.native.enabled>true</quarkus.native.enabled>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>


please help :)

I have solved it by replacing the following dependecies:
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
</dependency>

with these:
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jsonb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
</dependency>



For better forward compatibility, you can use the renamed artifacts: so quarkus-resteasy-reactive* -> quarkus-rest*
